# How to add a "veil" div to a table row

Tags: jquery, html-table

I don't know how to properly add a `veil` to a table row.

Please see this http://jsfiddle.net/gKVpm/

What I want to happen is that upon loading the first and third row of the table will be disabled by adding a div that will act as a veil to cover it. I tried to create a div (veil) dynamically but I don't know the right way to add the veil to the row. Please help.

Comment: Are you just trying to shade a row or do you need an actual blocking div?

Comment: From comments on the current answers, it sounds like he doesn't want anything in the row to be clickable, so a blocking div sounds like the route to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
function putVeil (rowNumber) {
    $("#tblData tbody tr:eq("+rowNumber+")").each(function(i) {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var veil = $('<div class="divVeil"></div>').appendTo('body').css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: offset.top,
            left: offset.left,
            height: $(this).outerHeight(),
            width: $(this).outerWidth()
        });
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gKVpm/3/)

Comment: Indeed, this is probably closest to what he wants.

Comment: If you want you can add a `opacity` too, to display the background

Answer (score 2):

What is the purpose of the veil `div`, exactly? From the looks of your fiddle, you just want to change the background color, in which case you can use jQuery's [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) function in conjunction with a CSS rule to just add a class to your `tr`s directly.

Something like this for your JavaScript:

```
function putVeil (rowNumber) {
    $("#tblData tbody tr:eq("+rowNumber+")").addClass("veil");
}
```

and this for the CSS rule:

```
.veil {
    background-color: #C3C3C3;
}
```

Fiddle for fiddling: http://jsfiddle.net/gKVpm/1/

If you want to use your "veil" idea for something more complicated, please let us know.

Comment: Yes. I want to make the veil disable any elements such as textbox. I tried adding some textbox inside and its still clickable.

Comment: I see what you mean now that you've clarified a bit. Arun P Johny's answer seems to be more what you want.

Comment: Yeah. I think so because I tried his answer and its seems to the one Im really looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Much easier, I would suggest to add a class to that row instead of using that "veil" that determines it is disabled and then use that css class name for validation using jquery, additionally, you can use that css class for style as disabled if that's what you also ask for.

Answer (score 1):

Put the style definitions for your class in the CSS. For `width` and `height` you can just set them both to 100% since the size is determined by the parent element.

http://jsfiddle.net/UjcB2/2

Comment: I forgot to mention how to make it on top of the row? I mean make the row really disabled?

Comment: @TheOnlyIdiot, the answer by Arun P Johny will give you a div that sits directly on top of your given row. Check his answer out.